# $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ can be made $\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} A_i$?

Tags: measure-theory

$K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact. $A_i \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open.

$K \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, then can one find $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $K \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} A_i$?

I believe I need to use the fact that every bounded sequence has convergent subsequence. But I am unsure, how to exactly use this.

Comment: That is the definition of compact set. Maybe if you add a few more words and say where exactly you have a problem or you got stuck, people can help you with your question.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Your example doesn't satisfy the assumptions. No, compactness is not about choosing the open cover yourself. The definition is that every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of compactness? That every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like, you can use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a metric space, and thus sequentially compact is equivalent to compact.

Proofs of this result can be found in any basic topology book. (Or for example here: http://people.clas.ufl.edu/mjury/files/sequential_compactness_notes.pdf )

Answer (score 0):

I'm also unsure how to use this fact directly. It would be much easier to prove this statement using the definition of compact sets via open covers: $K$ is compact if every open cover has a finite subcover. Applied here, it tells us that the given open cover of $K$ by the sets $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ has a finite subcover $\{A_{i_k}\}_{k=1}^n$, i.e. that $K\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_{i_k}$, for some indices $i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_n$. Then let $m=i_n$ (the largest of those indices), and observe that $K\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n A_{i_k}\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m A_{i}$ because the second union includes all the sets of the first union.